# Cannot resolve column (numeric column name) in Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is my data:

```
scala> data.printSchema
root
 |-- 1.0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 2.0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 3.0: string (nullable = true)
```

This doesn't work :(

```
scala> data.select("2.0").show
```

Exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`2.0`' given input columns: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0];;
'Project ['2.0]
+- Project [_1#5608 AS 1.0#5615, _2#5609 AS 2.0#5616, _3#5610 AS 3.0#5617]
   +- LocalRelation [_1#5608, _2#5609, _3#5610]
        ...
```

Try this at home (I'm running on the shell v_2.1.0.5)!

```
val data = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("Hello", ", ", "World!")
)).toDF("1.0", "2.0", "3.0")
data.select("2.0").show
```

Comment: I am reading an excel sheet file which has the dataset and converting it to dataframe, and then reading the dataFrame. I changed the column name from abc.xyz to 'abc.xyz' in the dataframe, but still I am getting the error : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`abc.xyz`' . What should I do now?

Comment: Did you use the "`" (key to the left of the "1" on a qwerty) before and after? See top answer below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [*backticks*](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html) to escape the dot, which is reserved for accessing columns for struct type:

```
data.select("`2.0`").show
+---+
|2.0|
+---+
| , |
+---+
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the reason for this is that the column name has a period in it. Spark is in general a little buggy as far as properly supporting backticks throughout codebase, but in this case they're fine.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is you can not add dot character in the column name while selecting from dataframe. You can have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665861/apply-automatically-backquotes-to-array-column-spark/42671494#42671494), kind of similar.

```
val data = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("Hello", ", ", "World!")
)).toDF("1.0", "2.0", "3.0")
data.select(sanitize("2.0")).show

def sanitize(input: String): String = s"`$input`"
```