# Not able to Select,Join on a attribute in dataset Apache spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

We are not able to perform any of the select join and other operation in apachae spark java for the field uniqueidrowid

Bellow is code  using to join two dataset.

```
  ManufacturerFileContent = ManufacturerFileContent .join(masterFileContent ,masterFileContent .col("uniqueidrowid").equalTo(ManufacturerFileContent .col("uniqueidrowidManufacturer")));
```

We even tried adding backtick(`) and also renamed the column to different name and we also tried adding separate column monotonically_increasing_id
and then joining using that common column all efforts are failed .

```
    +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------------------+--------------------------+
    |uniqueidrowid          |               prods|Prefix|             Prod ID| Normalized Manufacturer  |
    +-----------------------+--------------------+------+--------------------+--------------------------+
    |     0x000000000835ae0a|        aa 96K107   |   QQa|            9396K107|                      null|
    |     0x000000000835ae0b|     ff S-641-F-88  |   THa|         dS-641-F-88|                      null|
    |     0x000000000835ae0c|    gg Sff RIG-2549 |   GaE|        SfM RIG-2549|                      null|
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

we tried  monotonically increasing to create new column to join but the problem is not solved

```
masterFileContent = masterFileContent.repartition(1).withColumn("rowidsource", monotonically_increasing_id());
```

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name **"uniqueidrowid"** among (**uniqueidrowid**, prods, Prefix,...

Comment: can you please add join or problematic query to post?

Comment: clarity of the column which you are getting error needed generally if you have  dot chracter you have to select in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698322/cannot-resolve-column-numeric-column-name-in-spark-dataframe). you already told that backticks you tried. what is the column? where you have used ? all the details are needed